# Implementing Image Processing for Dimension Measurement in Arduino-based Packaging System

Tags: image-processing, arduino, computer-vision

I am working on an Arduino-based packaging system where I need to implement image processing for accurately measuring the dimensions of packages. I have a camera connected to the Arduino board, and I want to use image processing algorithms to analyze captured images and extract relevant information about the package dimensions.

I am looking for guidance on how to implement image processing algorithms on Arduino for this purpose. Specifically, I need help with the following:

Choosing appropriate image processing algorithms for edge detection, contour detection, and blob detection to identify package boundaries.
Converting pixel coordinates of package boundaries to physical units (e.g., inches or centimeters) for dimension calculation.
Optimizing image processing algorithms for speed and efficiency given the processing power limitations of Arduino boards.
Integrating image processing code with Arduino to control the camera, capture images, and process them in real-time.

I have researched various image processing techniques and libraries compatible with Arduino, but I am unsure about the best approach for my specific application. I have also experimented with basic image processing algorithms on Arduino, but I am struggling to achieve accurate and efficient results.